# Getting unwanted characters for apostrophe when reading data from a "|" (pipe) separated text file in R

Tags: r

I am trying to read data from a text file that contains data in the following format:

```
583550348352212992|Thu Apr 02 08:43:39 +0000 2015|Ambulance progress 'not fast enough' http://bbc.in/1P1AJyX
583406140337164288|Wed Apr 01 23:10:37 +0000 2015|Children’s hospital builds sleep app http://bbc.in/1BO9jlZ
```

I'm using the read.table function as follows:

```
bbchealth <- read.table(file=".../bbchealth.txt", 
                    sep="|", 
                    header = F, 
                    quote="", 
                    fill=F, 
                    stringsAsFactors = F,
                    numerals ="no.loss",
                    col.names = c("TweetId", "Date and Time", "Tweet"))
```

When I read the file, I see this:

```
583550348352212992 Thu Apr 02 08:43:39 +0000 2015 Ambulance progress 'not fast enough' http://bbc.in/1P1AJyX
583406140337164288 Wed Apr 01 23:10:37 +0000 2015 Childrenâ€™s hospital builds sleep app http://bbc.in/1BO
```

As you can see, the apostrophe in "Children`’`s" has been changed to `â€™`.

This is the case wherever the apostrophe appears (even in the inverted form).

```
574407194961039360|Sun Mar 08 03:12:01 +0000 2015|Frankie the dog ‘sniffs out cancer’ http://bbc.in/1COjVHM
```

is read as

```
574407194961039360 Sun Mar 08 03:12:01 +0000 2015 Frankie the dog â€˜sniffs out cancerâ€™ http://bbc.in/1COjVHM
```

Here, `‘` is converted into `â€˜` and `’` into `â€™`.

How can I ensure that these symbols are read as they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `encoding="UTF-8"` parameter in `read.table()`.